# What's the benefit of this long flight (apart from marketing)?

Tags: flight-path, flight-testing, boeing-787, online-tracking

The post [Do promotional flight routes have a historical precedent?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42603/14897) asks about previous occurrences.

I'm guessing [this flight](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/n7874/#e54ad6b) (shown below) was a test flight, as well as being a marketing attempt.

For a test flight, what would the benefit be?

[image]

Comment: Related question: [Flight path for promotion purposes - does this have a historical precedent?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42603/flight-path-for-promotion-purposes-does-this-have-a-historical-precedent)

Comment: @GregHewgill Bother - I did search the stack for n7874 and no matches were found.

Comment: I'm not saying you did anything wrong, I just happened to see both questions.

Comment: marketing came second, the first benefit is the flight testing.

Answer (score 7):

From the [this link](https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/boeing-uses-a-787-to-draw-a-787-dreamliner-during-etops-test/):

> At 15:38 local time N7874, the fourth 787 built, departed Boeing Field in Seattle for an 18-hour, 22 state test flight. The crew spent the overnight hours above the United States performing ETOPS testing on the new Rolls Royce Trent 1000 TEN engine, which will power the 787-10.

Also [this video](https://youtu.be/tS7iPBV9D68) from the above flightradar blog link.

The 18-hour flight was to test [ETOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETOPS), and there's no harm in some marketing as well. Also since the flight will be coming back to Seattle, it makes sense to keep the flight above the US, and near airports. Compared to venturing out in the ocean on a test.