# last 747 flight path, was this hand flown? How was this communicated with ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, autopilot, flight-path

Elal's last 747 flight made this nice path of a 747, how was this done?
Could this be entered into the computer and flown? or was this hand flown

The path looks quite neat

Also what is the ATC procedure for such a maneuver?

[image: last 747 flight]

Comment: Related: [How are special flight paths coordinated with ATC?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42600)

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't answer the first question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are special flight paths coordinated with ATC?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42600/how-are-special-flight-paths-coordinated-with-atc) @foot 's answer to that question also answers "Could this be entered into the computer and flown?".

Comment: well, that's just sad. I took an ElAl 747 JFK-TLV back in the early 80s. Other than being a smoking flight, stuck in the very back row in seats that didn't recline, it was quite the experience.

Comment: FYI: The flight is still on flightaware: https://de.flightaware.com/live/flight/ELY1747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe anyone could hand fly something that precise.  A series of waypoints could be entered in the flight plan in a "connect the dot" manner, then the autopilot could be put in NAV mode to fly the pattern.  Nothing that difficult about it though, it would just take some time.

If they are at 10,000 feet this could be done under VFR, in which case no "ATC Procedure" is necessary.  I am pretty sure though, that the flight would have communicated their intentions with ATC.

I am curious about area just off the end of the pointed nose.  I am guessing that they flew past this point and made a reverse turn, effectively creating a loop in the depicted track that is cut off in the picture.  Do you have a full screen shot showing this?  Because if it isn't there, then this was either all photoshopped, or flown, then the loop edited out later.  A 747 can't just turn on a point...

Comment: The nose is the entry and exit point, so it came in on the upper side, flew the "left" side of the aircraft, around to the right side and exited again on the nose to the north. [Here is a wider picture of it](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jamesasquith/2019/11/06/jumbo-jet-says-goodbye-by-drawing-a-massive-747-outline-over-the-sky/#40644cd86278).

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense, but why then is the aircraft symbol shown at the trailing edge of the right wing root as if it is completing the pattern there?

Comment: The screenshot is probably a play-back.

Comment: @MichaelHall You can see by the timeline at the bottom of the screenshot that this is a replay, the plane is just a little more than halfway through its flight.

Comment: "If they are at 10,000 feet this could be done under VFR, in which case no "ATC Procedure" is necessary" - Not really, you can be under VFR and still in controlled airspace thus requiring an ATC clearance for all movements.

Comment: Yes, I see now that it is a playback.  I'm not familiar with this format, seems odd that the full track is displayed before the aircraft symbol arrives.

Comment: @Ben, ok, I don't disagree, but would you care to put into an answer the ATC procedure the OP is asking about?  Perhaps:  "request vectors to outline the shape of my plane"?!

Comment: P.S.  I'm sure you know this seeing that you are a pilot, but for others reading this, just because you are in controlled airspace does not mean that ATC must clear your every move.